# From what horror film does this clip of a man flying behind another originate?

Tags: story-identification, horror, folklore

I recently watched Woodlands Dark & Days Bewitched, a documentary on the folk horror genre. It features clips of over 100 films, not all of which are flagged up to the viewer.

Toward the beginning of the final section, Folk Horror Revival, it features a sequences of a man with an injured nose who is distracted by something behind him and glances round. The camera angle allows us to see what he misses: that another man is flying, limbs flailing, behind him and out of a door.

Here are some photos I took from the TV of this sequence:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what this film is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those images are from ***[Hereditary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7784604/)*** (2018).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hereditary_(film)):

> *Hereditary* is a 2018 American psychological horror film written and directed by Ari Aster in his feature directorial debut. It stars Toni Collette, Alex Wolff, Milly Shapiro and Gabriel Byrne as the members of a family haunted by a mysterious presence after the death of their secretive grandmother.

The shots in question are visible at around the 1:39 mark in the video below.

Comment: Dang just too slow! Exactly what I thought it was too